# Fake an Expando

Tags: c#, .net, dynamic

I'm interested in implementing the `Expando` interface as a way to access complex data that is not in an Expando format.  I'd like to have expando-like Dynamic access, without reformatting into an Expando object.

So, how do you implement `IDynamicMetaObjectProvider`?

Here's a basic `ExpandoObject` definition:

```
ExpandoObject : IDynamicMetaObjectProvider
, IDictionary<string, object>
, ICollection<KeyValuePair<string, object>>
, IEnumerable<KeyValuePair<string, object>>
, IEnumerable
, INotifyPropertyChanged
```

Comment: Can you not just use `dynamic` to refer to everything? What do you mean by "complex data that is not in an Expando format"? More context would really help.

Comment: Have you considered inheriting from `DynamicObject`? That's a lot easier and doesn't involve `Expression`s.

Comment: @JonSkeet: The idea was "wouldn't it be good to have an Expando mapping layer to act as a facade."  It seems preferable to do this than to reformat the data into another structure via LINQ, etc.

Comment: @phg: I would consider doing that.  Have you come across any good examples of this?

Comment: @sgtz: What benefit would there be of *explicitly* using `Expando` rather than just typing a variable as `dynamic` in the first place? You still get the dynamic access that `Expando` gives you, but it will work with all your existing objects too. If that doesn't help you, please explain *why* you think it would be good to have an `Expando` mapping as a facade.

Comment: Look at `DynamicXmlNode` [here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/csharpfaq/archive/2009/10/19/dynamic-in-c-4-0-creating-wrappers-with-dynamicobject.aspx).

Comment: @phg: cool.  That's what I thinking.

Comment: @JonSkeet: specifically, to get around an issue that a 3rd party controls vendor introduces by not allowing indexer notation [] in bindings (whereas XAML does allow this).  The workaround for now will probably be something based on a Tuple idea.  Otherwise I wouldn't bother... but I like the link that phg posted + will explore this further.

Comment: You can easily overload indexers with `dynamicObject`, too.

Comment: @phg: do you want to post that as the answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, since you requested it, here's an untested example of adding indexers to the dynamic wrapper for `XElement` described [here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/csharpfaq/archive/2009/10/19/dynamic-in-c-4-0-creating-wrappers-with-dynamicobject.aspx) (I don't have .Net 4 on this machine, so please point out any errors):

```
public class DynamicXMLNode : DynamicObject
{
    XElement node;
    //all the other stuff necessary...

    public override bool TryGetIndex(GetIndexBinder binder, object[] indexes, out object result)
    {

        string name = (string)indexes[0];
        result = node.Attribute(name); //maybe check for null here
        return true;
    }

    public override bool TrySetIndex(SetIndexBinder binder, object[] indexes, object value)
    {
        string name = (string)indexes[0];
        node.SetAttributeValue(name, value);
        return true;
    }
}
```

Now you should be able to do this (using also the other methods defined like in the link):

```
dynamic contact = new DynamicXMLNode("Contact");
contact["type"] = "business";
contact.Name = "Patrick Hines";
contact.Address = new DynamicXMLNode(); // I think it should even work without this line. Can anybody confirm this?
contact.Address["street"] = "123 Main St";
contact.Address["city"] = "Mercer Island";
contact.Address["state"] = "WA";
contact.Address["postal"] = "68402";
```

producing

```
<Contact type="business">
    <Name>Patrick Hines</Name>
    <Address street="123 Main St" city="Mercer Island" state="WA" postal="68402" />
</Contact>
```

Also have a look at `TryConvert` in the example. It allows one to use the dynamic wrapper in places where the underlying type is expected -- which makes the whole thing totally awesome.

Finally, [here's](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.dynamic.dynamicobject.aspx) the list of `DynamicObject` members. The names are quite self-explanatory, and you can see that pretty everything you can do with an object can be overridden.

Comment: Alexei Levelkov's answer was more flexible, but I got this way of doing it working quickly.

Comment: That lies in the nature of dynamic. Only `IDynamicMetaObjectProvider` gives you _full_ flexibility, at the cost of having to deal with expression trees -- which can be a pain and doesn't pay for small wrappers like this. But I have always found `DynamicObject` to be enough up to now.

Answer (score 3):

Here is the link: [Implementing Dynamic Interfaces](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vstudio//ff800651.aspx) which has a sample (way to big to re-post here...)

Comment: I like how they totally misuse the phrase "dynamic programming".

Comment: we live in a dynamic world guys... everything is dynamic these days :-D